# Site deployment issue

Tags: deployment, three.js, live

I am trying to deploy my portoflio website live.
When I do so, 3d models and one of the fonts doesn't load.
Also on a mobile it is lagging.

But when i run locally on a live server, everything works just fine and smooth. All models and fonts are being fully loaded.

I've done npm run build, also tried reorganizing folders.

I am newbie and most probably making silly mistake, but couldn't fine solution so far.

Below is my code.

https://github.com/piotr-bania/Piotr_Bania_Portfolio_2022

Thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: Additional link to live page: https://piotr-bania-portfolio-2022.pages.dev/

Comment: Your website seems to be down. All I'm getting is [a 404 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404). I recommend you look at your developer console, and see what errors it gives you.